# Box2d polygon and circle shape conflicts FixtureA->GetBody() and FixtureB->GetBody()

Tags: cocos2d-x, box2d

I follow Raywenderlich tutorial on Cocos2d using Box2d to detect collision

My problem is ...

at first I use a polygon shape on both of my Box2d bodies.

when it collide the method is working fine.

However, when I change one of the bodies to Box2d circle shape, the method does not work correctly.

**FixtureA->GetBody();** return **FixtureB->GetBody();**

**FixtureB->GetBody();** return **FixtureA->GetBody();**

What I am trying to say is..

when I use circle shape instead of polygon shape on one of the body, it return the other way around (regarding 2 polygon shapes)

can someone explain how fixtureA and fixtureB is determined. Thanks! :)

**This is my collision method. I got it from GMTDev and Raywenderlich.**

```
std::vector<ContactData>::iterator pos;
for(pos = _contactListener->_contacts.begin(); pos != _contactListener->_contacts.end(); ++pos)
{
    ContactData contact = *pos;

    b2Body *bodyA = contact.fixtureA->GetBody();
    b2Body *bodyB = contact.fixtureB->GetBody();
    if (bodyA->GetUserData() != NULL && bodyB->GetUserData() != NULL)
    {
        Sprite *spriteA = (Sprite *) bodyA->GetUserData();
        Sprite *spriteB = (Sprite *) bodyB->GetUserData();
        int iTagA = spriteA->getTag();
        int iTagB = spriteB->getTag();

        if ((iTagA == 1 && iTagB == 2) ){
            //something is hit
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The way this is determined is not defined, so you should not assume that A or B will be some specific fixture. Write your code to handle both cases.

Comment: @iforce2d Thanks. So we can't determine which is fixtureA or which is fixtureB right?